# Generate unique filename for fswebcam

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu

I have `fswebcam` installed in my ubuntu. I want the `fswebcam` to provide output as img1, img2 (if img1 is there), img3, img4... etc

I tried:

```
sudo fswebcam img
```

It stores the files as **img** but replaces the existing one instead of storing as **img2**.
Is there any specific type of unix command to store the filename as I specified?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to patch ``fswebcam`` to do that.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is does `fswebcam` support a syntax that does what you want. I'm guessing no, and you should consider writing a script to `mv` the image after execution.

Comment: fswebcam does have --exec, which is formatted by strftime. Moving the captures to timestamped files would be possible with that, counting up still require some extra effort.

Comment: Yes.. But with the help of shell script that i posted below the page we can make it possible :)

Comment: @j.a. YEs. With your idea i have done a script program for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location="your location directory"
cd $location
ls
fname='filename'
i=1
j=1
    sudo fswebcam $fname 
    if [ -f $fname ]
    then
        echo "exist"
        while [ -f $fname$i ]
        do
            echo $fname$i
            i=$((i + j))
        done
        mv $fname $fname$i
    else
        echo "oops not found"
    fi
```

Answer (score 17):

Or you could just use its built in strftime capability to generate each file with the current time in the filename

```
--save pic%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to know that specific command if it exists. Meanwhile, I also needed to do that, and I used a workaround as follows (adapted to your needs):

```
f() {
    PREFIX="./img"
    FILES=$(ls $PREFIX* 2> /dev/null)
    LAST=$(sort -n <<<"${FILES//$PREFIX}" | tail -n1)
    echo $PREFIX$((LAST+1))
}
```

`FILES` contains al the filenames separated by `\n`.
`LAST` will have nothing, or the max number after the `$PREFIX`.
Finally, the function `echo`'es the last filename incremented by 1.

So, once you have defined `f` (or a more significant name), you can call your command like this:

```
sudo fswebcam $(f)
```

---

#### Example

```
$ ls
img1  img10  img11  img2  img3  img4  img5  img6  img7  img8  img9
$ echo $(f) # here I'm using "echo" instead of "sudo fswebcam"
./img12
```

---

#### `f` step by step

```
$ FILES=$(ls $PREFIX* 2> /dev/null)
$ cat <<<"$FILES"
./img1
./img10
./img11
./img2
./img3
./img4
./img5
./img6
./img7
./img8
./img9
$ LAST=$(sort -n <<<"${FILES//$PREFIX}" | tail -n1)
$ echo $LAST
11
$ echo $PREFIX$((LAST+1))
./img12
```